# Select part of the JSON that was filtered in the where

Tags: mysql, sql, json, database, collections

In the database I have a field called resources, in it I keep the permissions of a user, in the format Json:

```
[  
 {  
    "rota":"reserva",
    "sref":"oQueFazer",
    "ordem":"1",
    "recursos":[  
       "index",
       "show",
       "store",
       "update"
    ],
    "descricao":"Reservar",
    "controller":"ReservasController"
 },
 {  
    "rota":"reserva",
    "sref":"oQueFazer",
    "ordem":"2",
    "recursos":[  
       "index",
       "show"
    ],
    "descricao":"Reservas",
    "controller":"ReservasController"
 },
 {  
    "rota":"usuario",
    "sref":"oQueFazer",
    "ordem":"3",
    "recursos":[  
       "index",
       "show"
    ],
    "descricao":"Usuários",
    "controller":"UsuariosController"
 },
 {  
    "rota":"feriado",
    "sref":"home.feriado",
    "ordem":"4",
    "recursos":[  
       "index",
       "show",
       "store",
       "update",
       "destroy"
    ],
    "descricao":"Feriados",
    "controller":"FeriadosController"
 },
 {  
    "rota":"sala",
    "sref":"home.sala",
    "ordem":"5",
    "recursos":[  
       "index",
       "show"
    ],
    "descricao":"Salas",
    "controller":"SalasController"
 }
]
```

When I run the query to below, it gives me the correct return of which user has the permission:

```
SELECT recursos from perfis
WHERE
 JSON_CONTAINS(recursos, '{"controller": "FeriadosController"}');
```

Almost there, with the above select I get the record line I'm looking for, the problem is that it shows me the whole json collection that is in the resource field. (Of course he was going to do this, that's what I asked to run).

So for it to bring me the permissions that are allowed for a user in a certain controller, I made the select below:

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(recursos, '$[0].recursos') permite from perfis
WHERE
 JSON_CONTAINS(recursos, '{"controller": "FeriadosController"}');
```

And the return was:

```
["index", "show", "store", "update"]
```

That is, everything OK, it shows the permissions that the user has on a given controller, THE PROBLEM is that it show the permissions of the JSON collection of the first line `'$[0].recursos'` but that's not quite what I'm wanting, I want to return:

```
["index", "show", "store", "update", "destroy"]
```

What is the permission that the user has for the controller `HolidaysController`

That is, I am able to scan the controller to search in json, but I am not able to show the part of json that was searched, someone has a solution for this, jpa went through this?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use the following query (adjust as needed):

```js
SELECT
  JSON_EXTRACT(
    `recursos`,
    JSON_UNQUOTE(
      REPLACE(
        JSON_SEARCH(
          `recursos`,
          'one',
          'FeriadosController',
          NULL,
          '$[*].controller'
        ), 'controller', 'recursos'
      )
    )
  ) `permissions`
FROM
  `perfis`
WHERE
  JSON_CONTAINS(recursos, '{"controller": "FeriadosController"}');
```

See [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/akTWwyfhJnPBBBmzWAwmYd/0).